# mod_rewrite returns 302 found

Tags: windows, mod-rewrite, apache2, apache-config

I have an apache 2.2 and I am using mod_rewrite. My objective is to forward traffic from
http://localhost:80/AA to http://localhost:8090/BB. So I have a simple rule

RewriteRule http://localhost:80/AA http://localhost:8090/BB

My problem is that the client receives "302 Found". I was hoping that the RewriteRule will
forward the traffic from AA to BB and finally the BB will send the response to my client.

Is there a problem with my configuration?

Comment: I assume there are either two different web servers in play here, one listening on `80` and one listening on `8090`, or you have Apache listening on those 2 ports, with 2 different VirtualHosts?

Comment: a tomcat server is located at http://localhost:8090/BB. However I don't want to tell my client's to change the URL. So I installed an apache to use the mod_rewrite capabilities and send traffic from port 80 t0 8090. I don't know if this is the optimal solution...

Comment: I guess I am confused about your question. When you use mod_rewrite to redirect from one host to another, you *will* get two responses sent to your browser. The first is 302, which tells the browser to go to the second URL.  The second response should be 200.  Is the redirect working, except for the response codes?

Comment: @bmb. Thanks very much that you are taking the time to answer. I thought that with mod_rewrite I will have only one HTTP response. If I am taking 2, ie 301 and 200 OK this model does not work for me. Do you have any suggestion on how to do it? How can I make http://AA an alias with http://BB?

Comment: I added more info to my answer, but the short answer is I don't think you can do what you want using only mod_rewrite and your current setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left side, or pattern, of your RewriteRule should just be the filename you want to match, e.g. `^/AA$`. If you also want to make sure the host and port match specific values, you should set up RewriteCond's to match `%{HTTP_HOST}` and `%{SERVER_PORT}`. However the latter may be unnecessary unless your web server is configured for multiple domains and ports.

This is untested, but something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^localhost
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^/AA$          http://localhost:8090/BB
```

I would recommend that you try just this first:

```
RewriteRule ^/AA$          http://localhost:8090/BB
```

and add the RewriteCond's if you need them.

**Edit based on comments**: If you are trying to avoid the "302" response, you cannot do that for the situation you describe.  When you use mod_rewrite to redirect from one host to another, you will get two responses sent to your browser. The first is 302, which tells the browser to go to the second URL. The second response should be 200.

With mod_rewrite, you can avoid the redirect in the middle if the rewrite is from one page to another on the *same* server and port.  In that case, the rewrite is internal and the web server can respond with the BB page even though the request is for AA.  If you use a different server or port, the web server for AA does not have access to the page BB, so it responds with a redirect to the server that does have access.

If you can reconfigure your site to use the same port for AA and BB, you can make it work.  If not, I think you might be able to do what you want with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html). I have never used mod_proxy so I am not sure what you  would need to do.

Comment: I used only your RewriteRule and added [R=permanent,L] at the end of the line. The result was to send back error 301 to the client. What I want is the rule to forward from AA to BB and then the server at 8090 will send back http 200 OK to my client

Comment: Is the BB page at 8090 being successfully displayed?  If so, then it's working.  :80 is sending the 301 or 302 redirect and then 8090 is sending 200.  You cannot avoid the 301 in the middle when you redirect from one server to another with mod_rewrite.

Comment: the problem with mod_proxy is that you cannot use the question mark character in the substitution URL. For example foo.example.com/bar?lala will complain because ?lala is considered query string. That is the problem with mod_proxy – cateof 0 secs ago

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

What you wanna do is add the R flag to your rule, for redirection.

```
RewriteRule http://localhost:80/AA http://localhost:8090/BB [R=permanent,L]
```

`L` for last rule.

Comment: Did you check the headers returned? E.g. in Firefox with Firebug (or the like in other browsers) in the Net tab. Check for returned Headers (location and HTTP status code). So, did it redirect you to a 404, or does it return 404 on the first requested page?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to forward traffic, I guess `mod_rewrite` can't do that. You should preferably use `mod_proxy`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse

Example from the documentation:

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
   Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

Comment: the problem with mod_proxy is that you cannot use the question mark character in the substitution URL. For example http://foo.example.com/bar?lala will complain because ?lala is considered query string. That is the problem with mod_proxy

Comment: As in Apache documentation for ProxyPass Directive: _If you require a more flexible reverse-proxy configuration, see the RewriteRule directive with the [P] flag_. So try set [P] flag after your RewriteRule and this will omit 302 Found response code.